# Java 9: module not found: primefaces

Tags: java, maven, primefaces, java-9

I am migrating a webapp project to Java 9 which uses primefaces.

In the maven pom.xml primefaces was declared already properly:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
    </dependency>
 ...
</dependencies>
```

In module-info.java I added - as indicated by IntelliJ - a "requires primefaces;". So it looks:

```
module sharedwebapp {
    ...
    requires primefaces;
    ...
}
```

For other third party components this worked well. But for primefaces, I get the following error doing *mvn clean install* :

```
 >...shared-webapp/src/main/java/module-info.java:[9,14] module not found: primefaces
```

Is there anything I miss to declare?
Anything else to add?

Comment: What does `jar --file=primefaces-6.0.jar --describe-module` print?

Comment: Tried to list down the steps including above at [How to use 3rd party library in Java9 module?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46715853/1746118)

Comment: @AlanBateman: C:\Users\demo\.m2\repository\org\primefaces\primefaces\6.0>`jar --file=primefaces-6.0.jar --describe-module
              Moduldeskriptor kann nicht abgeleitet werden f³r: primefaces-6.0.jar
Provider class INSTALL not in module` ---- So this seems to be: `No module descriptor found.`

Comment: This is saying that the a module descriptor cannot be derived for the library, meaning it cannot be used as an automatic module. Can you check the META-INF/services directory, it suggests there is a service provider listed named "INSTALL" that is not in the JAR file.

Answer (score 1):

After the hint by Alan (see comment above) it turned out that there is a nasty text "INSTALL" in the following file:

primefaces-6.0.jar/META-INF/services/org.atmosphere.cpr.AtmosphereFramework

```
INSTALL
org.primefaces.push.impl.PushEndpointMapper
org.primefaces.push.impl.PushEndpointInterceptor
```

But apparently there are only classes expected. So I took a brute force solution deleting this text 'INSTALL':

```
org.primefaces.push.impl.PushEndpointMapper
org.primefaces.push.impl.PushEndpointInterceptor
```

Running *mvn clean install* now works like a charm...