# Hibernate IntelliJ - Unable to load class [org.postgresql.Driver]

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, intellij-idea

I want to run my own Hibernate application atop of a psql database set up in intellij:

[image: As you can see, I have the recent Postgresql Driver.]

https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/93/load.html
does not exactly explain how the xml should be configured...

This is the Error I get:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.4.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java --add-modules java.xml.bind "-javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=50395:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /Users/selfishound/Desktop/DBPRAK/3/Testat33/out/production/Testat33:/Users/selfishound/Desktop/DBPRAK/3/Testat33/lib/hibernate-commons-annotations-5.0.1.Final.jar:/Users/selfishound/Desktop/DBPRAK/3/Testat33/lib/dom4j-1.6.1.jar:/Users/selfishound/Desktop/DBPRAK/3/Testat33/lib/classmate-1.3.0.jar:/Users/selfishound/Desktop/DBPRAK/3/Testat33/lib/hibernate-jpa-2.1-api-1.0.0.Final.jar:/Users/selfishound/Desktop/DBPRAK/3/Testat33/lib/jandex-2.0.3.Final.jar:/Users/selfishound/Desktop/DBPRAK/3/Testat33/lib/antlr-2.7.7.jar:/Users/selfishound/Desktop/DBPRAK/3/Testat33/lib/jboss-logging-3.3.1.Final.jar:/Users/selfishound/Desktop/DBPRAK/3/Testat33/lib/jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec-1.0.1.Final.jar:/Users/selfishound/Desktop/DBPRAK/3/Testat33/lib/javassist-3.22.0-GA.jar:/Users/selfishound/Desktop/DBPRAK/3/Testat33/lib/hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar Main
Sep 20, 2018 1:21:51 PM org.hibernate.Version logVersion
INFO: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.16.Final}
Sep 20, 2018 1:21:51 PM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
INFO: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Sep 20, 2018 1:21:52 PM org.hibernate.annotations.common.reflection.java.JavaReflectionManager <clinit>
INFO: HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
Failed to create sessionFactory object.
Sep 20, 2018 1:21:55 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl configure
WARN: HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:271)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:233)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:242)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.handleTypes(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:352)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:691)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:726)
    at SessionFactoryClass.<init>(SessionFactoryClass.java:15)
    at PersonRelatedImpl.<init>(PersonRelatedImpl.java:16)
    at Menu.<init>(Menu.java:9)
    at Main.main(Main.java:4)
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [org.postgresql.Driver]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:348)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.loadDriverIfPossible(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:163)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildCreator(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:119)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:103)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:75)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:242)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:145)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:259)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : org.postgresql.Driver
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl$AggregatedClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:336)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:563)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:375)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:345)
    ... 29 more
```

What am I doing wrong here? I tried renaming the driver to  org.postgresql.Driver.jar and moving the jar to the root directory but that didnt help... It might have something to do with the configuration of IntelliJ, but this looks fine to me:[image]

Comment: You miss the jar containing `org.postgresql.Driver` in your classpath `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : org.postgresql.Driver`

Comment: Isn't it there in the top screenshot on the left inside the lib folder? 

edit: nevermind, I now understand what a classpath is. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IDE Data Source is not related to your application in any way including the way you configure the jdbc driver for it. You need to add the postgres jdbc driver jar to your [module's dependencies](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-managing-modules.html#working-with-module-dependencies). Note that if you are using java 9 modules you may need to add it via module-info file, see [How to use 3rd party library in Java9 module?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46714106/2000323).