# What is module-info and how to use it? Does it affect referenced libraries?

Tags: java, eclipse, import, classpath, eclipse-classpath

I have just upgraded to newest Eclipse and met some trouble.

I want to use jSSC library in my project and perhaps I am doing something wrong. At first, I am setting classpath choosing "Add External Libraries";

[image: classpath]

Then I click Finish and Eclipse asks me for the module name (I have never met it before). **Question 1: What is it about? What should be proper name here?** 
Anyway, I type something and proceed with "Create".

[image: moduleinfo]

Then I want to create Main class. This is how project looks like:

[image: project]

I am using sample code from:
https://code.google.com/archive/p/java-simple-serial-connector/wikis/jSSC_Start_Working.wiki

As you can suspect, there is import error in both files...

```
The import jssc cannot be resolved
```

**Question 2: What is causing the error? Why can't I import from the referenced library?**

**Question 3: Where should be module-info stored?**

The module-info code:

```
/**
 * 
 */
/**
 * @author username
 *
 */
module somemodule {
}
```

**Question 4: What should I put here?**
@Edit:
After marking my question as possible duplicate. I have tried to add

```
requires jssc;
```

in module-info. Didn't work and now I have one more error;

```
The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly 
referenced from required .class files
```

@Edit: I tried with Java 8 and everything is fine. There is no module-info.

Comment: have you tried using `jssc` as module name?

Comment: Just tried. Didn't work.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use 3rd party library in Java9 module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46713289/how-to-use-3rd-party-library-in-java9-module)

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System

Comment: I added "requires jssc;" to module-info and now I have:
The type java.lang.Object cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files