# maven-connector-java, module not found

Tags: mysql, maven, java-platform-module-system

Successfully I did my first JDBC program using MariaDB, Maven, Java-11.
Now I have to access MySQL and just exchanged the MariaDB dependency by

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>mysql</groupId>
  <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
  <version>8.0.28</version>
</dependency>
```

I figured out, that com.mysql.jdbc and com.mysql.cj and other modules are hosted in the mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar.
Hence, in module-info.java I exchanged

```
requires org.mariadb.jdbc;
```

by

```
requires com.mysql.jdbc;
```

I also tried

```
requires com.mysql.cj;
```

but still, the maven-compiler-plugin:3.9.0 complains

```
module not found
```

What did I miss, here?

Comment: It's obvious that the compiler plugin complains because the https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/mysql/mysql-connector-java/8.0.28/mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar does not contain a module descriptor (module-info.class) file... so this can't work. It does not even contain an Automodule entry in MANIFEST.MF...

Answer (score 1):

khmarbaise has put me on the right track: I almost forgot that there are legacy jar files around not prepared for easy integration into JPMS. 
To include the jar file **mysql-connector-java-8.0.28.jar**, which comes without a module-info.class, I had to enter

```
requires java.sql;
requires mysql.connector.java;
```

to my **module-info.java**.
The module name *mysql.connector.java* is derived from the name of its jar file by omitting the version info and substituting the dashes by dots.

Comment: the last statement would relate better with automatic-module-name.

Comment: That was one of my problems: Couldn't remember, how to build an automatic module name. But googling it led to a bunch of TLDR pages, without telling me (maybe I was too impatient).