# JavaFX project cannot find external libs using Java 11

Tags: java, javafx, jar

I'm using `OpenJDK 11`, `IntelijIDEA 2019.2` and `javafx-sdk-11.0.2`.

When I wrote JavaFX project, I tried to add external runnable jar from maven project, but IntelijIDEA didn't see classes for this jar.

What I've done:

I added as external library own jar.
[image]

In the project tree I found it:

[image]

But I couldn't create class objects and use methods that contains this jar:
[image]

Why it happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*If it's modular project*
The reason was the use of the file `module-info.java`. As we know, JavaFX 11 is not part of the JDK anymore. So, we need to add this special file at the root of our packages w/ lines like:

```
module modulename {
    requires javafx.fxml;
    requires javafx.controls;

    opens package;
}
```

From this moment, most likely you won't find classes until you add separately your jar in this code like:

```
requires name_of_jar;
```

Only after adding this, you can use your classes/methods from external libs.

---

*If it's non-modular project*
As mentioned by [mipa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57334464/javafx-project-cannot-find-external-libs-using-java-11/57334465#comment101165099_57334465), you can follow [these instructions](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/) as alternative way.

---

Related links:

- https://www.baeldung.com/java-9-modularity
- https://medium.com/criciumadev/its-time-migrating-to-java-11-5eb3868354f9
- [How to use 3rd party library in Java9 module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46713289/how-to-use-3rd-party-library-in-java9-module)
- https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html
- [IntelliJ can't recognize JavaFX 11 with OpenJDK 11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52467561/intellij-cant-recognize-javafx-11-with-openjdk-11)

Comment: Just in order to avoid any confusion. In order to use JavaFX 11 or higher you do not have to modularize your application and there is no need to create any module-info.java file. Just follow the instructions here: https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/

Comment: Thanks, mipa, useful info. I'll add it to the answer as alternative way.