# Required filename-based automodules detected - Javafx

Tags: java, javafx, jlink

I just built a JavaFX application and now I'm struggling to package it.

I'm getting the following error:
`Required filename-based automodules detected. Please don't publish this project to a public artifact repository!`

Specifically, these libs:

```
* Required filename-based automodules detected: [kafka-avro-serializer-5.3.1.jar, kafka-clients-5.3.1-ccs.jar, generex-1.0.2.jar]. Please don't publish this project to a public artifact repository! *
```

I've tried to just generate a jar with dependencies, but I have issues missing JavaFX runtime libs and it has become extremely cumbersome. In the above example, I'm attempted with javafx:jlink`

What are you my options to successfully run this as a standalone application I can freely distribute? I'm on Mac.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46713289/how-to-use-3rd-party-library-in-java9-module

Comment: https://github.com/moditect/moditect

Comment: This project shows how you can generate a self contained executable for you app, even if you have automodules: https://github.com/dlemmermann/JPackageScriptFX