# Gradle, error: module not found: kotlin.logging

Tags: kotlin, gradle, java-platform-module-system, kotlin-logging

These are my dependencies in [`build.gradle.kts`](https://github.com/kotlin-graphics/assimp/blob/master/build.gradle.kts#L55-L56):

```
    implementation("io.github.microutils:kotlin-logging:1.7.8")
    implementation("org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.29")
```

Then in [`module-info.java`](https://github.com/kotlin-graphics/assimp/blob/master/src/main/java/module-info.java#L13):

```
requires kotlin.logging;
```

All the rest works fine with the Java modular approach

However whenever I try to `build`, then I get:

```
> Task :compileJava FAILED
6 actionable tasks: 6 executed
C:\Users\elect\IdeaProjects\assimp\src\main\java\module-info.java:13: error: module not found: kotlin.logging
    requires kotlin.logging;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Automatic module name

```
PS C:\Users\elect> jar --file=C:\Users\elect\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.github.microutils\kotlin-logging-jvm\2.0.3\acd404001442be5d98fbaa7ff9df83041cba70fe\kotlin-logging-jvm-2.0.3.jar --describe-module
No module descriptor found. Derived automatic module.

kotlin.logging.jvm@2.0.3 automatic
requires java.base mandated
contains mu
contains mu.internal
```

Comment: What version of Gradle do you use?

Comment: @МихаилНафталь 6.6

Comment: Did you [activated](https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_java_modules_multi_project.html) module support?

Comment: yep, https://github.com/kotlin-graphics/assimp/blob/master/build.gradle.kts#L64

Comment: Have you derived the correct module name of the artifact to be used? Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46715853/1746118) on how.

Comment: @Naman, I updated my question, the extrapolated module name looks correct (I also tried to update to 2.0.3, which has now the `.jvm` postfix)

Comment: The module name looks appropriate in that way `requires kotlin.logging.jvm` with `2.0.3` shall work. Might be a setup issue with gradle etc.

Comment: Could it be dependency-dependent? I mean, the other dependencies work just fine..