# How to depend on java validation api /hibernate modules in java with gradle as build tool?

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, gradle, java-9

I have similar question as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46713289/9142279). However that question does not mention what build tool he is using and I assume that he is using maven as I didn't have problems with maven when using java 9 modules with it previously.

I am using the hibernate validator and I want to use java 9 modules, so I added a `module-info` file to the package of the module where I am depending on the validator api (the classes I am using are `Validator`, `ValidatiorFactory` , ... from packages like `javax.validation`)

I searched for these classes and found that they reside in this jar in my project dependencies: `validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar`, the classes I am using are inside package `validation`.

I used the command `jar --file=/path-to-the-jar-on-my-pc/validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar --describe-module` in the terminal and got the names of the modules exported from that jar:

```
No module descriptor found. Derived automatic module.

java.validation@2.0.1.Final automatic
requires java.base mandated
contains javax.validation
contains javax.validation.bootstrap
contains javax.validation.constraints
contains javax.validation.constraintvalidation
contains javax.validation.executable
contains javax.validation.groups
contains javax.validation.metadata
contains javax.validation.spi
contains javax.validation.valueextraction
```

So now when I put in my `module-info` file for example `requires javax.validation` the IDE complains that module is not found . I even added the dependency manually in the project structure (pressing `ctrl+shift+alt+s` to access it in intellij) where I added it from the path where it is stored in my machine but still same result.

I also tried the help tool from intellij and I found that it added `requires java.validation;` to my module-info and not `requires javax.validation;`, but anyway neither of them work.

I searched in `pom.xml` of that module and found this element `<Automatic-Module-Name>java.validation</Automatic-Module-Name>`, so now I am almost sure that gradle is causing the problem but I am no expert in gradle and how building tools work, so how can I solve this **with staying at using gradle as build tool**?

Comment: What version of Gradle are you using?

Comment: @Slaw Gradle 6.7.1

Comment: Does telling Gradle to use modules help (e.g. `java.modularity.inferModulePath.set(true)`)?

Comment: Yes, in your build script. As I wrote it in my comment I don't believe it needs to be in a closure. But you could do `java { modularity.inferModulePath.set(true) }` (though you might be able to do `= true` instead of `set(true)` if you're using the Groovy DSL, not sure).

Comment: @Slaw Yes it worked, the project compiled successfully (I put it in the root module's build.gradle as I am also using  a modularized app), please post an answer so I accept it, thanks alot, and Please if you may in your answer tell me why it didn't work out of the box (I mean in maven I don't recall adding  any extra configuration)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gradle didn't add proper support for the *Java Platform Module System* until version 6.4. However, you have to explicitly configure Gradle to work with modules.

```
// build.gradle
java {
    modularity.inferModulePath = true
}
```

Though if I'm not mistaken, `inferModulePath` is `true` by default as of Gradle 7.0.

For more information regarding Java modules and Gradle see https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_java_modules_multi_project.html

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Changing `javax.validation` to `jakarta.validation` resolved it.

build.gradle.kts:

```
implementation("jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:3.0.1")
```

module-info.java:

```
requires jakarta.validation;
```

I am using gradle java modularity plugin

https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.javamodularity.moduleplugin

here is what I set on my build.gradle.kts:

```
java {
    modularity.inferModulePath.set(false)
}

application {
    // Define the main class for the application.
    mainModule.set("modules.demo.gradle.consumer")
    mainClass.set("com.demo.gradle.consumer.Consumer")
}
```

I know `modularity.inferModulePath.set(false)` contradicts what Slaw wrote, but it is necessary if you use the plugin. See documentation

https://github.com/java9-modularity/gradle-modules-plugin