# After modularizing my java project how can I reference org.apache.commons.* libraries

Tags: java, module-info, apache-commons-csv

VSCode + Java 11

I am using the Apache commons libraries for a number of things in my project, specifically `org.apache.commons.csv` and `org.apache.commons.io`.

I am including the jar files for both in my `classpath` and I was building just fine until I put my code in a Java module for packaging.

Now I get `import` errors saying the packages are inaccessible, such as `org.apache.commons.csv is not accessible`.

If I try and refer to them directly in my own `module-info.java` like this...

```
module com.hupa {
    exports com.hupa.alg.cluster;
    requires jdk.xml.dom;
    requires org.apache.commons.csv;
}
```

I get the error `org.apache.commons.csv cannot be resolved to a module`, which seems correct as there is no module defined for it.

I am at a bit of a loss about what to do. There is no `module-info.java` or `module-info.class` in the jars I have for these libraries. How am I supposed to refer to them as dependencies for my project?

Comment: quick update, Java 11 is irrelevant. I have tried with later version of Java up to 18 and have the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

This could be helpful.

[How to use 3rd party library in Java9 module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46713289/how-to-use-3rd-party-library-in-java9-module)

The solution mentioned works for commons.csv. I'm using eclipse and maven for dependencies. Eclipse shows following warning though.

> Name of automatic module 'commons.csv' is unstable, it is derived from
> the module's file name.