# NetBeans 18 Maven JavaFX 20 project will not acknowledge smack [SOLVED]

Tags: linux, javafx, netbeans, xmpp, smack

I have a project where I intend to use XMPP for IM. I have called into NetBeans, the smack dependency and it shows in the pom.xml file as:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.igniterealtime.smack</groupId>
            <artifactId>smack-java8</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.igniterealtime.smack</groupId>
            <artifactId>smack-tcp</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.igniterealtime.smack</groupId>
            <artifactId>smack-im</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.igniterealtime.smack</groupId>
            <artifactId>smack-extensions</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

However, when I try to add smack to the moduleinfo or my code tries to import org.igniterealtime.smack there is an error...module not found. The clean and build with dependencies does download it and it is in my .m2/org.igniterealtime/smack folder.

I am really not sure what is blinding Netbeans from seeing what is in the local repo.

I have also tried to use the jivesoftware version with the same result. Not sure that is a valid test but that is what I have tried.

Anyone have a clue what is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide the correct module name for the smack dependency.

> when I try to add smack to the moduleinfo or my code tries to import org.igniterealtime.smack there is an error...module not found

This (probably) means that you have specified the wrong module name for smack in your module-info.  You did not provide the module-info in the question, so I don't know what the incorrect value you set there is.

The smack dependency does not have a module-info.  You can see this if you download the jar file and extract the contents.  It also does not have an `Automatic-Module-Name` setting in the manifest.  Therefore the automatic module name will be derived from the jar file.  The name is derived according to these (complex) rules in the [`static ModuleFinder of​(Path... entries)` documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/module/ModuleFinder.html#of-java.nio.file.Path...-), the gist of which is simply summarized in:

- [How to use 3rd party library in Java9 module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46713289/how-to-use-3rd-party-library-in-java9-module)

So the likely module name for the smack dependency is:

```
smack.java8
```

You can add that as a module to your project using this line in your `module-info.java`:

```
requires smack.java8;
```

You may need to do the same for your other smack dependencies (and perhaps other 3rd party libraries that your project is using), for example:

```
requires smack.java8;
requires smack.tcp;
requires smack.im;
requires smack.extensions;
```

You also need to ensure that the required dependency is on the Java module path (not the classpath).  Maven is aware of modular projects and will place the dependencies on the module path (even the automatic ones), if you use a recent Maven release.  When you import the Maven project into netbeans, I don't know if netbeans will configure the netbeans project to place required dependencies on the module path (I know Idea does that automatically for modular projects).

To learn more about automatic modules see:

- [What is an automatic module?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46741907/what-is-an-automatic-module)

I did not try to actually get smack to work in a modular project when composing this answer.

Not all non-modular software will work in a module environment, so there is a possibility that even if you set up the system as described above, you may still get failures. In which case it is likely best to make your project non-modular by removing the module-info.java from your project and specifying JavaFX module dependencies via VM arguments as documented for non-modular projects in the openjfx.io Getting Started documentation.

Comment: OK. Obviously, I was not very clear with my initial post.

The NetBeans 18 or 19 MAVEN plugin creates an entry into the pom.xml file for any dependency loaded from the MAVEN repo. That is the code shown in my post.

The configuration of the module-info you mention IS the problem. When trying to add the dependency as you describe it displays an error that the module is not known...even using the syntax you give as an example.  

No reason why yet...since every source I have seems to be saying something different.

Comment: Please re-read the last paragraph of my answer.  As you continue to have issue with modules, I advise you follow the suggested approach (non-modular project).  Trying to use software as a module that was not made to be modular is not very useful IMO.

Comment: Well, now I guess I am showing my ignorance. I fail to see the relevance of your last paragraph to my problem. This is a very large application with many modules and dependencies that do not have this problem. The smack and smackx are modules from igniterealtime available in the MAVEN repo.The resulting additions to pom.xml are shown. I have stated already that I have tried to add the "requires" statements to module-info without success. It produces an error "Module Not Found" even though the modules are defined as dependencies in the pom.xml. So...my question still stands. What am I missing?

Comment: *"What am I missing?"* -> Make the project non-modular.  It means that there is *no* module-info.  There are *no* requires statements.  And it is *impossible* to get a "Module Not Found" error.  Follow the instructions and templates for non-modular projects that I referenced -> the [openjfx.io Getting started with JavaFX NetBeans non-modular with Maven instructions](https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/).

Comment: *"The smack and smackx are modules from igniterealtime available in the MAVEN repo."* -> they are not -> those are non-modular jars, they are [not Java modules](https://www.oracle.com/corporate/features/understanding-java-9-modules.html).  Maven use or not does not matter, modularity for a jar is an attribute of the software itself.  If a jar has a module-info, it is a proper Java module, if it does not (and the smack jars do not), then it is not.