# module-info.java compile fail with maven-compiler-plugin and automatic modules

Tags: java, maven, java-9, java-module, module-info

I'm using v3.7.0 of the plugin as required and JDK 9.0.1. I have added two `requires` statements, each referring to a jar in the class path (automatic module). The module-info.java compiles successfully in Eclipse after I moved the jars to Modulepath. However, Maven gives me a compiler error saying one of them is missing (strangely, not the first one which is just one line before). I tried to check the automatic module name but I get an error from the commands just for this jar. What does this error mean and how do I fix it so that I can discover the proper module name?

I replaced my username in the output below. The jar in question does use a `ServiceLoader` but is not compiled with Java 9.

```
computerName:Commander-java username$ jar --file=/Users/username/.m2/repository/com/username/rcf/1.0/rcf-1.0.jar --describe-module
Unable to derive module descriptor for: /Users/username/.m2/repository/com/username/rcf/1.0/rcf-1.0.jar
Provider class com.username.rcf.server.TestCmdChain not in module

computerName:Commander-java username$ java -p /Users/username/.m2/repository/com/username/rcf/1.0/rcf-1.0.jar --list-modules
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Unable to derive module descriptor for /Users/username/.m2/repository/com/username/rcf/1.0/rcf-1.0.jar
Caused by: java.lang.module.InvalidModuleDescriptorException: Provider class com.username.rcf.server.TestCmdChain not in module
```

The answer in [How to deal with java keywords in auto generated module names in Java 9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46501388/how-to-deal-with-java-keywords-in-auto-generated-module-names-in-java-9) has a different error related to using a Java identifier in the module name. The automatic jar name for my module should just be `rcf` since the jar name is `rcf-1.0.jar`. The error I'm getting is different also.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deal with java keywords in auto generated module names in Java 9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46501388/how-to-deal-with-java-keywords-in-auto-generated-module-names-in-java-9)...  
Do you own the artifact `rcf-1.0.jar`?

Comment: Yes I do own it. I don’t have any Java identifiers in the name. It’s just rcf. The error seems to have to do with the ServiceLoader because the class mentioned in the error implements an interface that is used with ServiceLoader, but not sure. Can’t make sense of it.

Comment: Retracted duplicate vote. Ya seems like the implementation package [doesn't reside in the module](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46881513/1746118) itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> While deriving module description the contents of any
>   `META-INF/services` configuration files are mapped to `provides`
>   declarations.

The packages scanned for the services are the ones containing class files.

Also, the package name for individual classes is derived from their fully qualified name. From the shared logs `com.username.rcf.server` shall be the expected package name for the service to be provided and this shall turn into

```
provides x.y.z.TestCmdChainInterface with com.username.rcf.server.TestCmdChain
```

Seems like there is no such package `com.username.rcf.server` existing in your module.