# I can't import java.sql classes even that I have added them to the library

Tags: java, mysql, intellij-idea, jdbc, java-11

I tried watching many videos but still I can't import java.sql classes. I have edde them in my libraries too. I still can not figure out what have I done wrong. Please help me
I still haven't created the database though

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think you need a `requires java.sql` in your module definition. Can you post your module definition? https://stackoverflow.com/a/53005490/14955

Comment: `java.sql` has got nothing to do with the mysql connector - the former is a runtime class and the latter a JDBC driver

Comment: @Thilo Bro You're a life saver. It worked. Thank you very much.

Comment: @specializt MySQL Connector/J depends on java.sql though...

Comment: Do you have a `module-info.java` in your `src` folder?

Comment: @MarkRotteveel yes. Now I edited it as Thilo suggested now it’s okay

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java 9 migration issue - package com.mymodule is declared in unnamed module , module 'newmodule' does not read it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51888216/java-9-migration-issue-package-com-mymodule-is-declared-in-unnamed-module-mo)