# Spark 2.3.1 comes with a module name, spark.core.2.11, refused by module-info.java

Tags: java, apache-spark, java-module

I converted most of the sub-projects of my application to the new *Java* Module system that cames with Java 9+.

Eventually, when I come to the one that uses *Apache Spark*, I fall into a trap. *Spark* modules seems to be only available with names like "*spark.core.2.11*" which have numbers inside and are refused my the compiler.

```
module fr.pays.spark {
   requires fr.pays.geographie;
   requires fr.pays.territoire;
   requires fr.pays.fondation.objetmetier;

   requires spring.beans;
   requires spring.boot;
   requires spring.web;

   requires spark.core.2.11; // rejected for the numbers inside
}
```

I've found this link as a response on *Stackoverflow* : [Unable to derive module descriptor for auto generated module names in Java 9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46501388/unable-to-derive-module-descriptor-for-auto-generated-module-names-in-java-9). And I am thankful because it may be a solution (That I have to understand, and that I haven't tried yet).

However, it seems to me really clumsy. Aren't I misleading myself ?
One year has passed since the release of Java 9, and I figure that *Spark* must have changed to become fully compliant to Java 9+ now.

What is proper way to reference *Spark* modules today (I use the 2.3.1 version, the latest I've found) ?

If there none better available than the one the link suggest, do you know have information about when *Apache Spark* plan to fully integrate with the Java 9+ module system ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: They still don't have anything inlined as it [seems like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59844195/how-to-add-spark-dependencies-in-spring-boot-multi-module-java-11-project).

Comment: This question was asked two years ago. Is there a solution?

Comment: I think not, I and I believe if any solution comes, it will be with the version 3.0 of Spark. But it is just released, and I haven't experienced it.