# How to add Spark dependencies in spring-boot multi module Java 11 project

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, apache-spark, java-module

Whenever I am adding a module-info.java in my multi-module project I cannot import my Spark dependencies - everything else seems to be working

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-preview2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql_2.12</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.0-preview2</version>
</dependency>
```

[image: intellij import package screenshot]

IntelliJ tries to readd Maven Dependency without any result.

My module-info looks like:

```
module common {
    exports [...] 
    requires lombok;
    requires spring.data.jpa;
    requires spring.data.commons;
    requires org.apache.commons.lang3;
    requires spring.context;
    requires spring.web;
    requires spring.security.core;
    requires com.google.common;
    requires org.json;
    requires spring.core;
    requires spring.beans;
    requires com.fasterxml.jackson.core;
    requires com.fasterxml.jackson.databind;
    requires spring.jcl;
    requires spring.webmvc;
    requires mongo.java.driver;
    requires org.hibernate.orm.core;
    requires com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat.csv;
    requires java.sql;
}
```

It is not possible to add org.apache.* in my module-info.java either.

Is it possible that Spark is not ready for Jigsaw modules and Java 9+?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible that spark is not ready for Jigsaw modules and Java 9+?

It does hold true for `spark`. Two straight reasons that I can vouch for are:

1. They do not have an entry for

   ```
   Automatic-Module-Name: <module-name>
   ```

   in the artifact's `MANIFEST.MF` file.
2. If you try describing their artifacts using the `jar` tool

   ```
   jar --describe-module --file=<complete-path>/spark-core_2.12-3.0.0-preview2.jar
   ```

   This would fail to derive the module descriptor for a similar reason as mentioned in [this answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46501388/unable-to-derive-module-descriptor-for-auto-generated-module-names-in-java-9)

---

Few resources that might be useful once you reach here:

- [The reason why deriving automatic module name fails for spark artifacts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46501388/unable-to-derive-module-descriptor-for-auto-generated-module-names-in-java-9?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [A way to update a jar manually with the MANIFEST entry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46685325/1746118)
- [Spark's progress to Build and Run on JDK-11](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARKhttps://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-24421-24417)

Comment: Side note: Even when spark might be ready to be [build and run with JDK-11](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-24417), they do not expose artifacts that can be used on modulepath by others.

Comment: so it is not possible to use a module with java 8 and the rest of the project to be let's say 11? In  other words anything that depends on Spark needs to be downgraded to java 8 ? Or I could extract it as jar and use it in class path somehow? I thought jigsaw modules were optional with java >= 9  but it seems they are a requirement :(

Comment: @MichailMichailidis There are multiple considerations to it. First, if you are planning to create your application to be modular i.e. include a `module-info.java` in itself with JDK-11, then the only way would be updating the spark jar to manually add the entry in `MANIFEST.MF`. Second, if you plan to run on JDK-11, but using classpath, then you don't need a `module-info.java` and things should work fine without it as with Java-8. Then, if creating a modular application was the *only purpose* for you to migrate, you can very well remain with Java-8. You can choose accordingly for your app.