# TestNG - Unable to derive module descriptor for org.testng_6.14.3.r201802240500.jar Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, java-module

I am getting error when i trying to run TestNG project with Java 11 through Eclipse

Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Unable to derive module descriptor for C:\Users\ShefaliBajaj\Downloads\eclipse-java-2018-12-R-win32-x86_64\eclipse\plugins\org.testng_6.14.3.r201802240500.jar
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.testng.6.14.3.r201802240500: Invalid module name: '6' is not a Java identifier

Any advice how this can be fixed?

Earlier i was getting some 'Build path contains duplicate entry:'org.testng_TESTNG Container' for project error.
so to fix this i removed module info.java file 
and run the project and got above error

This is my first TestNG code-

```
package testng;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class TestNGBasics {

    @Test
    public void Demo()
    {
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to derive module descriptor for auto generated module names in Java 9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46501388/unable-to-derive-module-descriptor-for-auto-generated-module-names-in-java-9)

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because you can not add TestNG on your eclipse. Kindly install the plugin from eclipse marketplace. steps are given below:

```
 1. Click on Help.
 2. Click on eclipse marketplace
 3. Type TestNG + Enter
 4. Install "TestNG for Eclipse"
 5. After installation re-launch eclipse
```

Now it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs because TestNG plugin is not installed on your Eclipse IDE. TestNG may not be available on Eclipse Marketplace for all versions of Eclipse IDE.

To install TestNG:

```
1. Go to Help > Install New Software... > Add...
2. Name: TestNG Eclipse
3. Location: dl.bintray.com/testng-team/testng-eclipse-release/
```

Answer (score 0):

This Error Occurs usually due to the Java version we are using.

Follow the steps

1. Check for jre-1.8 in build path. If it is showing jre-1.5 then remove it.
2. Click on Add Library and then select JavaSystemLibrary
3. Click Next and choose Execution environment.
4. Select jre-1.8 or more from the dropdown.
5. Finish

[image]