# How to fix "Unable to derive module descriptor for .jar file" error in fxml

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, java-module

I would like to get an image from JAR library to my project.

```
    <graphic>
        <ImageView>
            <Image url="@/toolbarButtonGraphics/general/TipOfTheDay24.gif"/>
        </ImageView>
    </graphic>
```

I've added the library to my module and it seemed to be correct but the compiler throws an error:
*Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Unable to derive module descriptor for **filepath.jar**
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: jlfgr.1.0: Invalid module name: '1' is not a Java identifier.* Here's my module-info file:

```
requires javafx.fxml;
requires javafx.controls;

opens sample;
```

Comment: So you have your modular app, and you add a dependency (the jar with the image)?  This jar is `jlfgr.1.0.jar`? Why don't you add the jar to the module info? Have you tried renaming it to `jlfgr-1.0.jar`?

Comment: Adding to the module-info after renaming a file helped :) Thank you so much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to derive module descriptor for auto generated module names in Java 9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46501388/unable-to-derive-module-descriptor-for-auto-generated-module-names-in-java-9)

Answer (score 5):

it seems like you did not follow the steps properly. When you add a new library, first, you add it to your module and then you have to add it to you 
*module-info* file.

Just add a line in module-info 
---> `requires <package-name>;`

e.g my package name is *graphics-looks.jar*
---> `requires graphics-looks;`

P.S. before adding that jar anywhere, try to rename it and give a simple name by removing numbers and other characters from its name.

Comment: I faced the same issue mentioned above and this solution worked for me. Having numbers and special characters in my jar file was not allowing to add in the module-info file as it is. had to rename the jar file and use.

Comment: Package name having numbers and special character made it difficult to add it to the module-info. To make it clear, what worked for me is getting rid of the numbers and the special characters. Example: renaming jlfgr-1_0 to jlfgr

Answer (score 0):

Switch the project programming language, set it to version 11 on both sdk and language level. it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

**According to Tarun Dadlani Answer.**

Firstly, you need to add the `.jar` file to `Modules` as the pictures shown.
[Add .jar file to modules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9HtGz.png)

Secondly, you need to add a new lib to `module-info` file as the pictures shown.
[Add a new lib to module-info file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SMikG.png)

Finally, Rename the .jar file to give a simple name.