# FindException: unable to derive module descriptor

Tags: javafx

```
Error occurred during initialization of boot layer
java.lang.module.FindException: Unable to derive module descriptor for C:\JavaFX\jlfgr-1_0.jar
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: jlfgr.1.0: Invalid module name: '1' is not a Java identifier
```

I am getting this error again and again. I had tried all the solutions which are available on this site but my bug was not fixed. May any one please help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix "Unable to derive module descriptor for .jar file" error in fxml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55829893/how-to-fix-unable-to-derive-module-descriptor-for-jar-file-error-in-fxml)

Comment: please do some research before posting a question (typing the error description into you favorite search field will come up with answers, f.i. the duplicate, and is much quicker than typing an incomplete questions that might be closed as duplicate anyway <g>) - Also put a bit of effort into a good title .. is should be very short summary of the problem (vs. just stating there is some vague problem that you are unhappy with :)